# Want to remove "background" text

Tags: wordpress, background

How can I remove the text `background="">` from my Wordpress site?

The address is https://www.mybestroadbikes.com

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your body tag in header.php

The tag must must have been closed incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to delete if from the page source itself.

Here is where is the extra `String`

[image]

Hope this helps :)

EDIT:

I am not sure how you page is structured in WordPress but you can try when you are on the home page just click `Edit Page` in the top menu.

After that you will ed up in a `Dashboard` window with some `RichTextBox` on it. On the right side you have to option to switch to `Text` instad of `Visual`. When you do that I think you will be able to locate the extra `String` and remove it:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You've got an issue with whatever mechanism you have used to insert Google Tag Manager.  Use another method to whatever you have used or check your syntax because there's a syntax error with it.  You can easily embed the script in the header using the hook **wp_head**.

```
function child_theme_head_script() { ?>
   <script>
   //Script here
   </script>
<?php
}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'child_theme_head_script' );
```